# Appending to the beginning of a vector

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
vector1 = c(1,2,3,4)
```

I am specifying that I want to add the first x elements:

```
x = 3
```

I now want to replace vector1[1:x] with the sum of vector[1:3] and insert it at the beginning on the array:

```
sum_var = sum(vector1[1:x])
elem_remove = vector1[1:x]
vector1 = vector1[! vector1 %in% elem_remove]
```

Now that I have removed the elements I would like to replace, how would I add this variable sum_var to the beginning on the array? I don't want to replace the value stored in index 1 with sum_var, but would like to append to the beginning.

Comment: Hi! `vector <- c(x, vector)` will add element `x` to the beginning of `vector`. Best!

Comment: `c(sum(vector1[1:x]), vector1[-(1:x)])`

Comment: Seemed to do the trick d.b thank you!